# How to limit JVM creation?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I have created following class and ran on 15 terminals with command "java -Xms500m Class1".

I was expecting it to not allow me after 4 or 5 separate executions. I was expecting something like cannot create more JVMs but all programs are running. If each JVM creation requires 500Mb of initial heap memory (my RAM is 2GB) then the maximum limit of JVM creation should be four.

```
public class Class1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int i=0;
  while(true)
   {
    try
   {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
    System.out.println("hi-"+i);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException e)
   {
   }
   i++;
   if(i == 1000000)
   {
    break;
   }
 }
}
```

Thanks,
Amaresh

Answer (score 4):

`-Xmx` is the *maximum* heap size, `-Xms` is the *initial* heap size. See [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.de/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html) for more information about setting the heap size correctly.

Comment: Xmx doesnot force to use 500m by default,the actual memory usage depends on your program and it may be very less.

Comment: by mistake I wrote the command as "java -Xmx500m Class1" in my initial post but I tried with -Xms500m itself. After reading above link I tried setting maximum and minimum both to 500m still I am able to create several JVms.

Comment: As someone else said, it might be virtual memory. Use `top` or something equivalent to find out about the memory usage of your JVMs.

Comment: @michael667 : How to use top? I actually tried with -Xms, so I will expect 500MB to be allocated for each JVM.

Comment: On unix you can try `top` on the command line. On windows, use task manager.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to create JVMs with accumulative heap size bigger than your physical memory because of virtual memory.

In both Unix and Windows, because hard drive are used as memory, you can create 4GB + sizeof(hard drive space assigned to be used as memory) JVMs. So if you have 4GB of RAM and you assigned 2G of your hard drive to be used as memory, you can create 12 JVMs using java -Xmx500 -Xms500.

In Linux the swap space is use as memory. 
In windows the disk amount to be used as memory can be configured at `System Properties->Advanced->Performance->Settings`

Comment: [acmourya@blr2230651 ~]$ java -Xms 6000m Class1
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms
Could not create the Java virtual machine.


[acmourya@blr2230651 ~]$ java -Xms18000m Class1
hi-0
hi-1
hi-2
hi-3
hi-4
hi-5
hi-6
hi-7
hi-8
hi-9
hi-10
hi-11
hi-12
hi-13
hi-14
hi-15
hi-16
hi-17
hi-18

Answer (score 1):

Try using `-Xms500m` as well. That will set the initial memory.

You were setting the "maximum" memory - but your code doesn't use much memory at all.

Your OS probably also has virtual memory, so it will go a little more than 2GB.

Also, remember that the `500m` is the heap size. The actual JVM will take a little more memory than the heap alone.

Comment: I tried with "java -Xms500m Class1"  and "java -Xms500m -Xmx500m Class1" . Still more than 10 similar executions are happening.